# What does additional nodes in js heap dump signify

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, v8

Steps to Repro:

1) Make a simple index page.
index.html

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

2) Take Heap Snapshot dump in ChromeDevtools.
[image]

3) Clearly It shows 5 body elements instead of 1.
    3.1) what does the other 4 body elements signify here?? 
    3.2) How to identify the one which maps with what we created in our html.